# Is it good to start and shutdown threads in a loop?

Tags: java, executorservice

In this code, I am using two threads to work on two tasks. After the tasks  complete, the ExecutorService is shutdown. And then it continues to process the next pair of 'sku' & 'inputText'. Two threads are created again to process the two tasks, and shutdown. It continues this way until all input are processed.

Is this a normal way to use multiple threads in a local method? I am afraid it may not be good to create and shutdown ExecutorService local variable frequently in a method.

```
 // defined as an instance variable 
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);


 public ExtractedInfo execute(String sku, String inputText){ 

 ExtractedInfo info = new ExtractedInfo();    

 Callable<List<Subgraph>> retrieveTask = () -> {
        return this.retrieveAllAttributesFromGraph(sku);
    };
    Callable<String> parseTask = () -> {
        return this.executeParser(sku, inputText);
    };

    Future<List<Subgraph>> retrieveService = executorService.submit(retrieveTask);
    Future<String> parseService = executorService.submit(parseTask);

    String inputLine = null;
    List<Subgraph> allAttributes = null;

    try {
        inputLine = parseService.get();
        allAttributes = retrieveService.get();
    }catch(ExecutionException ee){
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }catch (InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    **executorService.shutdown();**

    info.setInputLine(inputLine);
    info.setAttributes(allAttributes);

    return info;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you declare `executorService` as a property of a class instead of a local variable?

Comment: @Ivan, let me think about it. Thanks

Comment: @Ivan, please see my updated. Then should I call the 'executorService.shutdown()' method? The "execute()" method has to be called for each 'inputText'. So I guess the 'shutdown' method shouldn't be called inside the method?

Comment: If you use Spring you could check `DisposableBean` interface and override `destroy()` method

Comment: look at the JavaDoc. you only need to call `.shutdown()` when you do not want the service to accept anymore tasks. Which in most applications is when all the work has been queued and you want the application to quit when the last thread is completed.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome, my don't control or have access to the end point of the whole application. My application provides a service for downstream application through a public interface. So in such a case, I guess I shouldn't shutdown the executor service, once the application starts. For each call of the method above, my application processes the input, return the result and continue with the next input.

Comment: I am really not sure WHY it's put on hold. It is a very concrete question, i.e. how or whether to shutdown an executor service in the situation I described as above.  It's not about a style question, it's about the correctness of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the actual things implementing the tasks’ business logic aren’t the pooled threads. There’s no bleeding over of state from the tasks (Runnables or Callables) to the threads executing them. So there’s no reason to discard perfectly good threads and go get new ones.

When the application shuts down is a good place to shutdown your threadpools. Web applications let you register a ServletContextListener where you can implement this kind of thing, in the contextDestroyed method.

Comment: So in my case, probably I don' need to call the shutdown() method, because my application provides an interface for other applications to call my service, and I don't control the end point of the whole application. Is that true? Is there any potential harm without shutting down the pool?

Comment: @user697911: not shutting down threadpool keeps the jvm from exiting.

Comment: @user697911 as Nathan mentioned, if you do not shut down your pool, JVM will be still running. It might be an issue for standalone desktop application or for an application with exact workflow (like do A then B then C then shut down). But for applications that are running 24×7 it's not an issue because they are usually shut down externally (for deployment or other stuff)